# How do I filter out elements in a column of a data frame based upon if it is in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I'm trying to filter out bogus locations from a column in a data frame. The column is filled with locations taken from tweets. Some of the locations aren't real. I am trying to separate them from the valid locations. Below is the code I have. However, the output is not producing the right thing, it instead will only return France. I'm hoping someone can identify what I'm doing wrong here or another way to try. Let me know if I didn't explain it well enough. Also, I assign variables both outside and inside the function for testing purposes.

```
import pandas as pd

cn_csv = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/cntry_list.csv") #this is just a list of every country along with respective alpha 2 and alpha 3 codes, see the link below to download csv 
country_names = cn_csv['country']

results = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/results.csv") #this is a dataframe with multiple columns, one being "source location" See edit below that displays data in "Source Location" column  
src_locs = results["Source Location"]
locs_to_list = list(src_locs)

new_list = [entry.split(', ') for entry in locs_to_list]

def country_name_check(input_country_list):
    
    cn_csv = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/cntrylst.csv")
    country_names = cn_csv['country']
    
    results = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/results.csv")
    src_locs = results["Source Location"]
    locs_to_list = list(src_locs)
    
    new_list = [entry.split(', ') for entry in locs_to_list]
 
    valid_names = []
    tobe_checked = []
    
    for i in new_list:
        if i in country_names.values:
            valid_names.append(i)
        else:
            tobe_checked.append(i)
    return valid_names, tobe_checked

print(country_name_check(src_locs))
```

**EDIT 1**: Adding the link for the cntry_list.csv file. I downloaded the csv of the table data. https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/country-codes
Since I am unable to share a file on here, here is the "Source Location" column data:

| Source Location |
| --- |
| She/her |
| South Carolina, USA |
| Torino |
| England, UK |
| trying to get by |
| Bemidiji, MN |
| St. Paul, MN |
| Stockport, England |
| Liverpool, England |
| EH7 |
| DLR - LAX - PDX - SEA - GEG |
| Barcelona |
| Curitiba |
| kent |
| Paris, France |
| Moon |
| Denver, CO |
| France |

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: `cn_csv = pd.read_csv("cntry_list")` does not look right - no extension (csv). But just an observation of your 2nd line.

Comment: The no csv extension is a mistake when typing the file path, I just modified the file path for simplification purposes. I will make an edit that fixes that mistake and also add the data!

Comment: When you take into consideration that the words `England`, `UK` and `USA` **are not** within the column `country` within the `ctry_list.csv` file, what other country were you hoping to match ?

Comment: @ScottC Thanks for mentioning, I did not even notice I only had the country col selected. I did this at first just for testing to see each country and never deleted it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find and list country names, both valid and not, you may filter the initial `results` DataFrame:

```py
# make list from unique values of Source Location that match values from country_names
valid_names = list(results[results['Source Location']
                           .isin(country_names)]['Source Location']
                   .unique())
# with ~ select unique values that don't match country_names values
tobe_checked = list(results[~results['Source Location']
                            .isin(country_names)]['Source Location']
                    .unique())
```

Your unwanted result with only France being returned could be solved by trying that simpler approach. However, the problem in your code may be there when reading `cntrylst` outside of the function, as indicated by [ScottC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20174226/scottc)

Comment: Thank you Nikita, I tried this. For some reason, it still only returns France as the valid name.

Comment: Now I see where the problem is: `country_names` contains country's full name, but `src_locs` is a mess that needs trimming and brushing. You then split `src_locs` entries by `,` which on a larger dataset would likely produce much more country names, but in your case the only entry that matched a real name was France only (two times, in fact), because neither England or USA were in `country_names` as well, though seemed promising. I guess you weren't wrong from the start!